# How Do I Complete "048 The King of Curries"?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch

There is a spice vendor in Al Mamoon who is looking for a few items.  On my way to get them I've come across an old man who also wants a few items in order to give me what the original vendor wanted.

What are all of the items I need to complete this quest and where can they be found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a Youtube tutorial here on this specific mission and the ingredient locations (if you want to watch through the entire video).